# Pivot table component for angular 2?

Tags: angular, pivot-table

I'm looking for a UI component with some rich pivot table features.

I took a look at ag-grid. Seems to be the right fit, but it's not free and this is a not an option at the moment. Maybe in the future it can be possible, but for now it has to be free.

If there's not option for angular 2 would it be a good idea to workaround with a vanilla javascript component?

Comment: have you found any other pivot table component for angular2?

Comment: I quit looking for it as we had more important needs at that moment.

Answer (score 3):

Refer **igPivotGrid** from Ignite UI-

http://igniteui.github.io/igniteui-angular2/samples/igPivotGrid-XmlaDataSource/igPivotGrid-XmlaDataSource.html

Sample component-

```
import {Component, Inject, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {IgPivotDataSelectorComponent, IgPivotGridComponent} from "./src/igniteui.angular2.ts";
import {bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'

declare var jQuery: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: "./igPivotGrid-XmlaDataSourceTemplate.html",
    directives: [IgPivotDataSelectorComponent, IgPivotGridComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
    private optsGrid: IgPivotGrid;
    private optsSelector: IgPivotDataSelector;
    private selectorId: string;
    private gridId: string;
    private data: any;

    constructor() {
        this.data =  new jQuery.ig.OlapXmlaDataSource({
            serverUrl: 'http://sampledata.infragistics.com/olap/msmdpump.dll',
            catalog: 'Adventure Works DW Standard Edition',
            cube: 'Adventure Works',
            rows: "[Ship Date].[Calendar]",
            columns: "[Delivery Date].[Calendar]",
            measures: "[Measures].[Product Gross Profit Margin Status],[Measures].[Product Gross Profit Margin Goal]",
        });

        this.selectorId = "dataSelector";
        this.gridId = "pivotGrid";

        this.optsGrid = {
            dataSource: this.data,
            height: "650px"
        };

        this.optsSelector = {
            dataSource: this.data,
            height: "650px",
            width: "30%"
        };
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

html template:

```
<h1 class="push-down-md">igPivotGrid  using XmlDataSource</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ig-pivot-grid [(widgetId)]="gridId" [(options)]="optsGrid">
        </ig-pivot-grid>
        <ig-pivot-data-selector [(widgetId)]="selectorId" [(options)]="optsSelector">
        </ig-pivot-data-selector>
    </div>
</div>
```

This might suites your requirement. See if this helps.